# Grabbing values of genered ListBox ASP Controls inside ListView On PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I've got this:

```
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvAttributes" DataKeyNames="attribute_id" OnItemDataBound="lvAttributes_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <label class="title">product <%# Eval("name") %></label>
            <asp:ListBox DataTextField="value" DataValueField="tag_id" CssClass="chzn-select"
                runat="server" ID="lbAttributeTags"></asp:ListBox>
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Now on post back I'd like to get each individual lbAttributeTags selected value. But as you know there might be a single ListBox generated or 100. So how should I approach a solution for this for the many potential possibilities?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell me in which PostBack you wanted to get the list box value? It that any click event outside of the ListView or any click event inside that?

Comment: The button that causes the PostBack is `outside` of the ListView. In either case, could you please show me both ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have the code to fetch the selected item from the ListBox inside the list view control

asp.net

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
</div>
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvAttributes" DataKeyNames="attribute_id" OnItemDataBound="lvAttributes_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <label class="title">product <%# Eval("name") %></label>
        <asp:ListBox DataTextField="value" DataValueField="tag_id" CssClass="chzn-select"
            runat="server" ID="lbAttributeTags"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnInsideLV" runat="server" Text="Inside LV Click" OnCommand="btnInsideLV_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>' /><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:Button ID="btnSample" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="btnSample_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="lblDisplay" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="lblSelectedRowValue" runat="server" />
</form>
```

c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class stackoverflow_12761515 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("name");
            dt.Columns.Add("attribute_id");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["attribute_id"] = i + 1;
            dr["name"] = "item " + i + 1;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        lvAttributes.DataSource = dt;
        lvAttributes.DataBind();

        //BindListBox();
    }
}

private void BindListBox(ListBox lb)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("value");
    dt.Columns.Add("tag_id");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["tag_id"] = i + 1;
        dr["value"] = "value " + i + 1;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    //ListBox lb = (ListBox)lvAttributes.FindControl("lbAttributeTags");
    lb.DataSource = dt;
    lb.DataTextField = "value";
    lb.DataValueField = "tag_id";
    lb.DataBind();
}


protected void lvAttributes_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = (ListBox)e.Item.FindControl("lbAttributeTags");
    BindListBox(lb);
}

protected void btnSample_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblDisplay.Text = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < lvAttributes.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        ListBox lb = (ListBox)lvAttributes.Items[i].FindControl("lbAttributeTags");
        if (lb.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            lblDisplay.Text += lb.SelectedItem.Text + "\n";
        }

    }
}
protected void btnInsideLV_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int selectedRow = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    ListBox lbCurrent = (ListBox)lvAttributes.Items[selectedRow - 1].FindControl("lbAttributeTags");
    if (lbCurrent.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        lblSelectedRowValue.Text = "Row selected is : " + selectedRow + " and list item is : " + lbCurrent.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        lblSelectedRowValue.Text = "no item selected";
    }
}
```

}

The 2 button click events have the code which you required. Please let me know if you need anything else.